# javascript to find the caller div. (or any other dom object)

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following html page:

```
<div id="a" onclick ="javascript:click();">a</div>
<div id="b" onclick ="javascript:click();">b</div>
<div id="c" onclick ="javascript:click();">c</div>
```

Now, The javascript function:

```
function click() {
   // how do I know if it was 'a' , 'b' or 'c' to call me 
}
```

Does anybody know how to find (in every browser) which div was the caller in the 'called' click function ?

Many Thanks
Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

js:

```
function click(elem){
     alert(elem.id);
}
```

html:

```
<div id="a" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">a</div>
<div id="b" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">b</div>
<div id="c" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">c</div>
```

Comment: Lose the ineffective `javascript:` labels.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
<script>
function click(me) {
   alert(me.id);
}
</script>
...
<div id="c" onclick ="click(this);">c</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  you are right. 
The trick was to call the 'click' method by passing 'this' as argument.

Excellent

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as function argument:

```
<div id="a" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">a</div>
<div id="b" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">b</div>
<div id="c" onclick ="javascript:click(this);">c</div>
```

And here is the function:

```
function click(el) {
  alert(el.id);
}
```

It would have been easier and unobtrusive with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) though:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
});
```